# Get calling context in a service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-context

So I'm working on a `service` that will handle requests to send data to a socket.

I've done socket programming in a `service` before, but only within the same application. I'd like this to just sit and do nothing until any application wants to give it data to send. That's all well and good.

I have register an `intent filter` and the usual stuff and can process the data. But I want to process the data coming from different activities in different threads (subsequent calls from the same application will be computed on the same thread).

Is there a way to get the calling package or app or whatever? I'd prefer not to require passing in an identifier as an extra to prevent spoofing. (It's not a serious security concern, it's just each application needs its data processed in the order that it's received.)

Answer (score 0):

I had run to the same issue in the past. I couldn't find a way to know how send the intent and I ended up adding an extra.

If you don't want to use an extra perhaps you might want to set an `Action` but it's almost the same thing.